# USB 3.0 Device not enumerated on USB 3.0 Port in Debian 6.0 OS

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, usb

I have installed Debian 6.0 OS (Linux kernel 2.6.32 )to test my USB Application as well as Driver.

My USB device is working fine on USB 2.0 Port without any issue.

But when i tried to connect the same device on USB 3.0 port at that time it enumerated as USB 2.0 Dvice not as USB 3.0 device which i have seen from dmesg output.

Following is log of `dmesg` output of my device which is enumerated as USB 2.0 device not as USB 3.0 even if USB device is connected in USB 3.0 port.

```
[  945.271232] usb 3-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
```

This is the output of lsmod with xhci support.

```
#lsmod | grep xhci
usbcore               123175  4 usbhid,ehci_hcd,xhci
```

This is the snap output of lsusb -v of my USB device

```
#lsusb -d 1552:0004 -v
 wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
```

Please find the kernel and OS information below

```
#uname -a
Linux debian64 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 22:14:43 UTC 2013 x86_64  
GNU/Linux
```

so, USB 2.0 support maximum packet size as 512 bytes while USB 3.0 supports maximum packet size as 1024 bytes. It seems that my device is enumerated as USB 2.0 Device not as USB 3.0 Device.

Is there any older kernel (2.6.32) issue which can not able to enumerate USB 3.0 Device or any thing else?

Please let me know any feedback if any one has faced this type of issue or any one knows about this issue.

Comment: Please let me know if any one has idea about this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Does your device correctly work at USB3.0 mode on the same or different machine with any other operating system? More importantly, if not confidential, what's the device?

Comment: Yes. The device is working fine on ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Linux kernel 3.2.0 on USB 3.0 Port without any issue.

Comment: Is there any issue regarding older linux kernel which i am using currently?

Comment: What makes you think it is not USB 3? The message I see is `usb 3-1.2:`.

Comment: The Device is enumerated as USB 3.0 Device as you can see from dmesg like "high speed USB device using ehci_hcd". If Device is enumerated as USb 3.0 the at that time you will get message like "superspeed USb Device using xhci_hcd" message in dmesg output. I have also tried with other USB 3.0 device but could not succeeded to enumerate as USB 3.0 device and problem remains same. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Could you show the entire kernel version? Post the output of `uname -a`. I found a [post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=88854) complaining of a similar problem for 2.6.32-5. [This](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=61600) might also help.

Comment: # uname -a
Linux debian64 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 23 22:14:43 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux                                                I have also edited uname -a command output in my question also. so you can also find from question.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: I found [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614801) bug report. Since USB 3 support was added in  2.6.31 it was still very immature in the 2.6.32. Various people have reported problems. Is it essential to have your device work with a minor kernel release that is almost 4 years old?

Comment: I have checked my device on Ubuntu 12.04 with Linux Kernel Release 3.2.0 and it is working fine on uSB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Port without any issue. So, How can I determine from which kernel as well as from which debian release this issue has been fixed? Do you have any idea about this? Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: do you know this issue can be solved if i update the Linux kernel from 2.6.32 to 3.2.0?

Comment: I have also looked into kernel 2.6.32 through make menuconfig command and found that it is supporting USB 3.0 support with xhci host controller Driver as experimental use not as full support. So, it seems like they were doing some experiment on USB 3.0 on that Older Linux Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your question, your device is indeed recognized as a USB 3 device. I don't see any problem here. The `dmesg` output you posted is

> [  945.271232] **usb 3-1.2**: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4

Compare tat to what I get when connecting a USB 2 device:

> [121568.653226] **usb 2-1.4**: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci

Comment: But whenever I looked into the Device info using lsusb -v command at that i found that wMaxPacketSize is 512 Bytes which is for USB 2.0 not for USB 3.0 stack. wMaxPacketSize is 1024 Bytes for USB 3.0 Device. So it seems like the device is enumerated as USB 2.0 Device not USB 3.0 Device. I have also tried with other USB 3.0 devices in which i got the same problem. Also, USB 3.0 device is enumerated from xhci_hcd which loaded while running lsmod | grep xhci. But Device is failed to enumerate as USB 3.0 Device as per the dmesg and lsusb -v command output.

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati please [edit] your question to include this information. At the moment, there is nothing in your question that indicates you have a problem. Include the `lsusb -v` output.

Comment: I have edited my question with snap of USb device info of lsusb -v command output. I can not give full information as it is confidential details which i can not disclose.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information regarding USB Device or Linux OS related information.

Comment: `usb 3` mean it is attacched to the port/hub 3 but `high speed` and `ehci` are 2.0.

Comment: @Alex, Yes. You are right. I have attached my USB device USB 3.0 Port but it enumerated as USB 2.0 Device not as USB 3.0 device. So, it displays high speed with ehci host controller not super speed with xhci host controller.

Comment: Do you have more idea about how to solve this issue?